# Using abstractions for form fields when using Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using [formik](https://formik.org/) as a library to handle form data.

For some fields, I would like to use a different underlying type, e.g. I use [decimal.js-light](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js-light) for handling of decimal values*.

So in my form values, I'd like my decimal types to be represented by this type. However, when the user is typing, it should still treat the input as string rather than a number. A classic example is if the user wants to change "1000" to "2000", if they delete the "1" and enter a "2", the value would become "20", if the input is treated as a number during typing.

We also need to handle the user's locale (the locale depends on the country of the tenant that the user is a member of, not the browser settings).

So when the form is loaded, I need to convert the decimal to a localized string.
When I submit the form, I need parse the string in the user's locale, [which is not trivial](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/localized-number-parsing).

There are also some dependent fields, e.g. I have a quantity and amount field - and we calculate the a total as quantity*amount (using decimal.js). So now I have the rules for localized parsing 3 different places, when submitting, when validating input, and when calculating the total.

Are there patterns for formik for dealing with a different underlying abstraction of the type of data you're working with?

* We use decimal.js because JavaScript doesn't handle decimal precision, e.g. 0.1+0.2 does not equal 0.3. For many scenarios this doesn't matter, but in my application, I need decimal precision.

Comment: Why do you need to do the conversion in formik itself? Can't you do the conversion outside formik, i.e, first while retrieving the initial data (number to string) and inside the `onSubmit` method (string to number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in the end, we do have 3 sets of data types:

- numbers that we get from the server and that should be saved (either in number or string format if it is required to be saved with high precision)
- `formik`s fields of type `Decimal`
- and, formatted strings to be represented to the end user.

Representation of the data can be easily extracted to the separate encapsulated layer.

One of the formik's `Field` arguments - is `component`. You can use it to create a separate component that will play only with the field value, format it as it should be, and show it to the end user. So, the formatted value will live only inside that component. It would not be exposed outside. There is a pretty library([react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format)) that can deal with it in a sophisticated way.

It may be done like the following:

```
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format'
import { Field } from 'formik'

const FormattedPrice = () => {
  return <Field component={NumberFormat} thousandSeparator="," {/* ...otherProps */} />
}
```

or:

```
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format'
import { useField } from 'formik'

const FormattedPrice2 = () => {
  const [{value}] = useField('price')

  return (
    <NumberFormat
      thousandSeparator=","
      prefix="$"
      value={value}
      {/* ...otherProps */}
    />
  )
}
```

If you use material UI, its `TextInput` component also has a prop `component` where you can pass your custom decorator or use an existing solution of `react-number-format`. I guess there should be all cases handled that you may expect to have. And documentation is pretty exhaustive.

It means, that you don't need to manage the actual state of formatted data, all you have to do - is provide some configuration.

String localization would also be the responsibility of that decorator component.

After this - we will have raw values in our `formik`s context. And, all that is left - is to write some mappers to convert numbers to `Decimal`s and provider them as an `initialValues` to `formik` and vice versa - map `Decimal`s to numbers somewhere in the `onSubmit` after data is validated. That part may be extracted to separate helper class to handle all in one place and make his functions self-annihilating. The approximate interface of that class:

```
import Decimal from 'decimal.js-light'

type BackendResponseData = {
  price: number
  // other fields
}

type FormValues = {
  price: Decimal
  // other fields
}

interface DataConverter {
  storedDataToFormValues(storedData: BackendResponseData) => FormValues
  formValuesToStoredData(formValues: FormValues) => BackendResponseData
}
```

Comment: There's a bit more to it than this, but you got me in the right direction. E.g. the `NumberInput` takes `number`s as input, not `Decimal` instances, so I wrapped than in a `DecimalInput`, and merging with MUI `TextField` also was a bit of work. And that doesn't plug straight into the `component` prop, as all field props are found in a special `field` prop - and formik by default hooks into `onChange`, but that carries the string value, not decimal, ... I will probably post the entire solution when I have it cleaned up slightly.

Comment: @Pete did you ever get to a workable solution? I'm trying to solve the same problem with formik and mui, where the values that need to be displayed are constructed from different data fields.